# Block IP range while accepting one of the IP in the range

Tags: iptables

We would like to block IP range but at the same time allow only one IP in the range. From searching we found this:

```
 $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s <ALLOWED_IP> -j ACCEPT
 $ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ALLOWED_IP> -j ACCEPT

 $ sudo iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range <NOT_ALLOWED_RANGE> -j DROP
```

but it's not working. We also tried reversing the order but still not working:

```
 $ sudo iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range <NOT_ALLOWED_RANGE> -j DROP

 $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s <ALLOWED_IP> -j ACCEPT
 $ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ALLOWED_IP> -j ACCEPT
```

what could we be doing wrong?

Comment: You've got the order wrong. Try as follow `iptables -I INPUT -s IP_TO_ALLOW -j ACCEPT` then run `iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range RANGE_TO_DROP -j DROP`.  Where `-A` means `APPEND` and `-I` means `INSERT`  which inserts the rule on top of the table.

Comment: @val0x00ff Thanks for tip. Now it works after putting order correctly.  I had also missed on correct usage of `A` and `I`. In case you want to put an answer I will get it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comment the order matters!

To be on the safe side, netfilter encourages to change `iptables` policy for the `INPUT` chain to drop so then you only allow IP addresses or ranges you want.

To answer your question, you first allow the desired IP address using the `-I` flag which indicates that you want to put the rule on top.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s SOURCE_IP -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range SRC_RANGE/CIDR -j DROP
```

In `iptables` the first rule applies which means that the rule on top will always win.

```
DENY  (this rule wins)
 |
ALLOW
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to use `-I` option for such case in general. Having rules in such order:

```
-A INPUT -s ALLOWED_IP -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s FORBIDDEN_IP_RANGE -j DROP
```

allows only connections from `ALLOWED_IP` while denying connections from other addresses in `FORBIDDEN_IP_RANGE`.

The problem is that topic starter used `-I` option in the wrong place - for `DROP` action and thus in both cases `DROP` action was placed on the top.

Here is what `man iptables` says:

> -I, --insert chain [rulenum] rule-specification
>
> Insert  one or more rules in the selected chain as the given rule number.  So, if the rule number is 1, the rule or rules are inserted at the head of the chain. This is also the default if no rule number is specified.

So, using `-I` without rule number simply defaults to rule number 1. You should be careful with such usage since it can break logic of more complex firewall configurations.